# Making integral ∫ use \limits by default with unicode-math

Tags: symbols, math-operators, unicode-math

How can I make the unicode integral symbol ∫ act as if it is followed by `\limits`? Classically `\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}` would do. But with `unicode-math` this does not help anymore. I also tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{∫}{∫\limits}

\begin{document}
    \[ ∫_a^b f(x) dx \]
\end{document}
```

But that seems to lead to an infinite recursion

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the macros `\removenolimits` and `\addnolimits` to change the limits for specified operators.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\let\limU\removenolimits  %limit position up
\let\limR\addnolimits     %limit position right

\begin{document}
Example
    \[ ∫_a^b f(x) dx \]
\limU{\int}
    \[ ∫_a^b f(x) dx \]
\limR{\int}
    \[ ∫_a^b f(x) dx \]
\end{document}
```

You'll have to swicht with `\limU/R` for each operator you want to change the limits position. (Tested with LuaLaTeX)

Comment: Works also with XeLaTeX.

Comment: How can I make this only apply for `\displaystyle`? I want to keep rightward limits for inline math, but have `\limits` on by default for all `\displaystyle` integrals…