# Integral limits with amsmath in LuaLaTeX

Tags: amsmath, luatex, math-operators

Also reading the thread about [Making integral ∫ use \limits by default with unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65319/making-integral-use-limits-by-default-with-unicode-math) I'm not quite happy with the solution.
With pdfLaTeX I use the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[A=\int_0^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

and get

[image: Screenshot of result with pdflatex]

Compiling the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\[A=\int_0^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\]
\end{document}
```

with LuaLaTeX I get

[image: Screenshot of result with lualatex]

Is there any possibility—beside the solution in the linked question—to get the same output with both pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`unicode-math` uses a different model for deciding whether to put limits over or beside integrals and the `intlimits` option does nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\removenolimits{\int}

\begin{document}
\[
A=\int_0^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The list of operators defined with an implied `\nolimits` is the following:

```
\int\iint\iiint\iiiint\oint\oiint\oiiint
\intclockwise\varointclockwise\ointctrclockwise\sumint
\intbar\intBar\fint\cirfnint\awint\rppolint
\scpolint\npolint\pointint\sqint\intlarhk\intx
\intcap\intcup\upint\lowint
```

You can remove items from the list (one at a time) with the `\removenolimits` command; there's also `\addnolimits` for adding to the list.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. When I typeset your code, the limits of the integral are not exactly possitioned like your picture shows but some points moved to the right.
Do you know, why this happens?

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk You're right: I used XeLaTeX for typesetting the example. With LuaLaTeX there's a shift, which seems like a bug somewhere.

Comment: @egreg: it is probably the difference in calculating the integral width due to the bug in applying italic corrections to integrals in LuaTeX.

Comment: Is there any update on that bug? I still get the wrong output using LuaLaTeX from TeX Live 2014.

Comment: @Socob The bug seems to be still present. You should ask to the LuaTeX mailing list: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/luatex